# How to read client machine time in pageload event?

Tags: c#, javascript

I am using javascript to get client date as below

```
function getDate() {
var dt = new Date();
return (dt);  
}
```

I want this value in pageload ? How to assign javascript return value to a variable ?
after page load javascript is calling , but I want the result to the variable  in the pageload.

Comment: There are many function available which you can use before actual loading of window i.e. `window.onload = function() {}`

Comment: @I-droid I think he (or she) wants to get the client date from server side code otherwise he wouldn't have placed 'C#' as a tag of this question

Comment: Thanks Leo.. i want to to get Client date from server side code

Answer (score 0):

try setting a value in the window object on your pageload event like this;

```
window.loadDateTime = getDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `window.onload` event which is called when the `DOM` is loaded. You can attach this function as a handler to that event.

```
window.onload=function()
 {
  var dateNow=getDate()
 };
```